# Selected Index of dropdown not working after jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, c#-4.0

I have a dropdown which I filled on pageload event like below:

```
                DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Add New1", "1"));
                DropDownList1.Items.Insert(1, new ListItem("Add New2", "2"));
                DropDownList1.Items.Insert(2, new ListItem("Add New3", "3"));
```

Now I need to fill this dropdown using Jquery button like below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#btnFillValue").click(function () {            
            $("#DropDownList1 option[value='2']").attr("selected", "selected");
            $("#DropDownList1 option[value='1']").removeAttr("selected");
        });
});
```

This query code fill the 2nd item(Add New2) in the dropdown.But from here the problem started, now when I change my drop down to index 0 it is not going to its DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged event and the more strange part is if I choose any other item except 0 it is working fine. Don't know why this strange issue occur.

Any quick help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: @Cory:But my problem is not related to filling dropdown, I am not getting the IndexChange after the value being changed after Jquery button click and IndexChange not calling only for index 0 for other index it is working fine even after jquery button click.

Comment: do you have a value at index 0?

Answer (score 0):

To resolved this issue I have to add one extra item in ddl at index "-1" like below:

```
DropDownList1.Items.Insert(-1, new System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem("--Please Select--", "4", false))
```

The above code works for me perfectly. Hope this helps to anyone.